# Generate OTP in Android and get first and last 2 digits of mobile number

Tags: android

I generate OTP after getting the phone number but now I want the FIRST TWO digits and LAST TWO digits of the mobile number.

For example, if user enters 9866523487 as the mobile number then OTP will be 9887.

Comment: Convert to string and get the first 2 Index and last 2 Index using the `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` String method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method in your code.

```
String generateOTP (String number) {
StringBuilder otp = new StringBuilder("");
    if(number != null) {
        otp.append(number.substring(0,2));
        otp.append(number.substring(number.length() - 2, number.length()));
    }
    return otp.toString();
}
```

This method uses the substring properties of a string. Read in details from here. [Substring in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/substring-in-java/).